# Can I still trade existing EOS on Binance after Launch Day?

Tags: exchange, mainnet

I'm using *Binance* exchange service to trade EOS against ETH and BTC.

On [eoscountdown.com](https://eoscountdown.com) we can read:

> EOS tokens will become frozen on the Ethereum blockchain on June 2, 2018 22:59:59 UTC. The mainnet launch will occur shortly thereafter.

Do I need to take any extra steps (like [registration](https://busy.org/@eosgo/how-to-own-your-eos-on-launch-day)) before the Launch Day (June 2, 2018) to continue trading on Binance to avoid tokens being frozen, or I can still trade as usual after that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Binance has confirmed support of the token registration for it's users](https://support.binance.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001649171-Binance-Will-Support-EOS-MainNet-Token-Swap), so for that reason you can leave them on the exchange safely and still be credited with the official EOS coin when it launches.

However just because they will auto-register you doesn't mean you will also receive all the possible airdrops that will be happening in early June. The safest course of action to maximize your airdrop participation (and revenue) is to hold your own EOS in a wallet (off-exchange) that you control the private key for - due to this, you should register your own tokens and not rely on Binance.

As for trading, the ERC20 tokens will be permanently frozen so you won't be able to trade between June 2nd and the time the mainnet launches and you're credited your own EOS Coin.

For all users looking into registering your tokens, I'd recommend doing so immediately as the first airdrops to require registration are starting in the next 36hours (May 10th 2018). https://steemit.com/eos/@evolutionos/evolution-airdrop-may-10th

Here's a very useful [guide on how to register your tokens offline](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1GUpjc5hkw&feature=youtu.be) for maximum security created by EOS New York (a bp candidate). The guide uses the official EOS repositories so there's no need to rely on any 3rd party code.

Comment: Are there any more details on how Binance exactly will manage the registration?

I'm worried about the lack of details (even though I trust Binance), because optimally they would ask you for a new EOS public key that you have generated yourself and then would register that for you.

If they don't do that, then the only other way I see it working is that they generate a new EOS keypair for you! And then they control the private key. Even if they give you the private key it means they owned it at some point at least.

Optimally you register the tokens yourself to a new EOS key you own.

Comment: @Soleone they haven't confirmed any other details beyond the link I posted. If I had to guess as a developer, this is how I'd handle it:

Since an exchange uses one ETH private key for all its tokens for all users, I'd simply register that address with the EOS crowdsale on behalf of my users. Step 2, I'd run a for loop that runs through all of my user's frozen ERC-20 EOS balances and credit them an equivalent amount of the new EOS coin from my new wallet created during the registration. If at the end of the loop the total amount of ERC20 EOS tokens === the EOS Coins, it worked.

Comment: @Soleone follow-up to your edited question. They will definitely control the private key of your coins, that's how exchanges work, this isn't specific to EOS. Once they've credited you your EOS coin you can then withdraw them to your own wallet in which you control the private key.

Comment: Now here's the thing I don't quite follow: They don't have the power to "credit" EOS, all they can do is register ETH addresses or claim ICO tokens. So I assume they have to use "register". The way that works is you have to provide an EOS address. Once the main mainnet (and a bunch of secondary nets) go live the block producers for those use the snapshot of the ETH addresses to actually credit the token holders.

Comment: @Soleone I think your confusion lies with how exchanges operate. Exchanges use a hot wallet which analogous to a bank account shared between all their users. They keep everyone's tokens here, usually these accounts hold balances in the millions. In your account details they keep in the database they know just how many coins are owned by `soleone` and how many by `altshiftdev`. They then 'credit' each of us the appropriate amount you can withdraw up too. In theory, you could  withdraw even more than you own because it's not a real wallet, simply a ledger that their system keeps track of.

Comment: I understand that part. My misunderstanding is that I assumed they will actually register the tokens for you so that you show up (have some way to claim your spot) in the snapshot. But I guess instead they will not do that and just wait until they receive EOS from the mainnet and then transfer you that EOS. Which means that any new networks that are based off the snapshot besides the official mainnet you have to beg Binance to send you tokens from that chain as well because they will have access to it. Not the end of the world, but I would definitely recommend everyone to register themselves.

Comment: Exactly! That's why I mentioned registering yourself in the second part of my answer.

Comment: I registered mine with crowdsale contract, using the Exodus wallet. is it valid for the airdrops? @altShiftDev

Comment: @LeoRibeiro as long as you've hit the 'Claim All' button and control your own EOS on an Ethereum address then you'll get airdrops.

Comment: @altShiftDev I followed this: https://support.exodus.io/article/690-how-do-i-register-my-eos-address-inside-exodus and I'm not sure where to hit "Claim All" button...

Comment: The claim all button is only for those who purchased from the crowdsale, you've either already done this if you registered using that guide or you bought your EOS from an exchange in which case claim all isn't relevant.